# Ajax. SyntaxError. Invalid character

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an asp.net mvc application. I have view named "Access", controller and I'm tring to call one of controllers method in ajax. And I got an Syntax Error. Method Test was not called at all

Controller method code:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Test(string p)
{            
    return Json(new User() {  Name="Nat"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "Access/Test", // the method we are calling
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       data: { "p": "test" },
       dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
                alert("yes");
                alert('Yay! It worked!' + result);                
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert('Not worked ' + error);
        }

});
```

It is a very simple code but I cann't force it work.I want to understand why my json data is incorrect and I got an Error. And I want to execute my method

Answer (score 0):

You send `GET` request, so remove `data` and `contentType` - they are no needed in `GET` requests:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "Access/Test", // the method we are calling
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (result) {
                alert("yes");
                alert('Yay! It worked!' + result);                
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert('Not worked ' + error);
        }

});
```

And remove `p` from action, or set it to null:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Test(string p = null)
{            
    return Json(new User() {  Name="Nat"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. AccessContoller.cs

   ```
   public class AccessController : Controller
   {
     [HttpGet]
     public JsonResult Test(string p)
     {            
        return Json(new User() {  Name="Nat"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
   }
   ```
2. Index or Any Page Call

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "Access/Test", //First Controller Name(Access) or After Method Name
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       data: { "p": "test" },
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (result) {
           alert("yes");
           alert('Yay! It worked!' + result);                
       },
       error: function (request, status, error) {
           alert('Not worked ' + error);}
      });
   });
   ```